# Stop Scheduler after Specific Time

Tags: java, akka, scheduler, actor

I am trying to create a Scheduler in AKKA.
Requirement is :-

1. It will start every day 5:00AM
2. It will stop at 10:00 PM every day
3. It will execute job in every 1 hr (Frequency).

I find the solution for 3rd point (Frequency) but not able to find the solution for 1st and 2nd point.

```
 system.scheduler().schedule(Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS), Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.HOURS), actorRef, "Hello", system.dispatcher(), null);
```

Comment: It is same as the 3rd point. Just use different method and time for it.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to schedule a `Runnable` with the required frequency. In the runnable, add a condition to check whether you are in the required time interval and only send the message in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
// For 5.00 am time period. 

int InHrs = 17;
int InMinutes = 00;

scheduler = Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(Duration.create(nextExecutionInSeconds(InHrs, InMinutes), TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                Duration.create(24, TimeUnit.HOURS),
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Call your method
                        System.out.println("EVERY 24:00 Later ---    " + System.currentTimeMillis());   

                    }
                },
                Akka.system().dispatcher());


public static int nextExecutionInSeconds(int hour, int minute){
            return Seconds.secondsBetween(
                    new DateTime(),
                    nextExecution(hour, minute)
            ).getSeconds();
        }

public static DateTime nextExecution(int hour, int minute){
        DateTime next = new DateTime()
                .withHourOfDay(hour)
                .withMinuteOfHour(minute)
                .withSecondOfMinute(0)
                .withMillisOfSecond(0);

        return (next.isBeforeNow())
                ? next.plusHours(24)
                : next;
    }
```

Repeat this for 10 AM time period which will be 22 inHrs. Hopefully it solves the problem.

Comment: But it will run the job only once in a day. I have to run this job frequently (every hr or every 30 min).

Comment: as you said you have found the solution for 3rd point. so I didn't apply source fo it. but you can use it for 1 hr also.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I am using this for scheduling and repeating, it is working fine
//**I am also searching for to Stop Scheduler after Specific Time**
 public static void setReminder(Context context, Class<?> cls, int hour, int min, int uniqueAlertID)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar setcalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        setcalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        // cancel already scheduled reminders
        cancelReminder(context,cls, uniqueAlertID);

        if(setcalendar.before(calendar))
            setcalendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);

        // Enable a receiver
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, cls);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqueAlertID, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setcalendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }

    public static void cancelReminder(Context context,Class<?> cls, int uniqueAlertID)
    {
        // Disable a receiver
        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, cls);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                uniqueAlertID, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
```